# presence style try method for possible attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a more ruby-like way of conditionally call a method if it exists?

currently doing:

```
count = if thing.respond_to?(:sometimes_available)
  thing.sometimes_available 
else
  thing.do_expensive_query_to_get_available
end
```

For example sometimes I query a collection and select extra attributes

```
Thing.join(:authors)
  .select('things.*, count(authors.id) as sometimes_available')
  .group('things.id')
```

**Would be great to do something like:**

```
thing.presence(:sometimes_available) || thing.expensive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you're probably looking for is probably [ActiveSupport#`try`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try)

`try` will actually return `nil` even if the object does not respond to the method you're sending it.

You could then re-write your code as:

```
thing.try(:sometimes_available) || thing.expensive
```

Under the scenes, it's doing similar logic to what you're doing

```
def try(*a, &b)
  if a.empty? || respond_to?(a.first)
    # omitted for simplicity
    a.public_send(*a, &b)
  end
end
```

Comment: Would be nice to at least get a reason for the down vote when this clearly works for what the OP is asking ;)

Comment: can you link to the source code? my `try` method looks different. it does not use `respond_to?` and actually throws an error `def try(*a, &b)
    if a.empty? && block_given?
      yield self
    else
      __send__(*a, &b)
    end
  end`

Comment: Oh sad. my project is rails3. Your solution was introduced in rails4

Comment: [Actual DHH commit that introduces Rails `Object#try`](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/99ea1a875b06feb4346869f371e2a57a2cc0a0fc)

Comment: @BlairAnderson you could still bring that patch into your Rails 3 project. I didn't include the entire source code as it was a bit irrelevant to what you wanted answered. In any case, I'm glad you found the source and hope it helped you solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Marking the previous answer as correct, but wanted to clarify:

Rails4 introduced a monkeypatch to `Object#try` that also does what i have explained above

**link to commit:** https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/99ea1a875b06feb4346869f371e2a57a2cc0a0fc